# rebuild the TABLE visitors from the TABLE history with a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, datatable

A small disaster happened to me on my database postgresql ver. 8.4. 
Help me please!

I have to follow my visitors on my webpage in two tables like:

TABLE **history**

```
whereseenlast   varchar(50)
uniqid          varchar(13) primary key
whenseenlast    timestamp
bla1            varchar(10)
bla2            varchar(10)
bla3            varchar(10)
```

**example**:

```
where1.html, **1**, 2000-01-01 00:00:00, somebla1, somebla2, somebla3
where2.html, **1**, 2005-05-05 05:06:07, somebla1, somebla2, somebla3
...
where12345.html, **1**, 2012-11-22 11:22:33, somebla1, somebla2, somebla3
```

TABLE **visitors** (uniqid is primary key, each visitor can be found just once in this table)

```
wherseenfirst   varchar(50)
whereseenlast   varchar(50)
whenseenfirst   timestamp
whenseenlast    timestamp
uniqid          varchar(13) PRIMARY KEY
notes           varchar (20)
xyz             varchar(20)
```

**example**:

```
where1.html, where12345.html, 2000-01-01 00:00:00,  2012-11-22 11:22:33, 1, somenote, somexyz
```

I accidentally deleted the TABLE visitors and I have no backup. But, I am sure it is easy for an expert to rebuild the TABLE visitors from the TABLE history with a query.

(I know I will not be able to restore the **notes** and **xyz** COLUMNS from TABLE **history** but that is not a big deal)

Could you please suggest solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your home assignment for database class?

You first have to select the latest and earliest rows from History for every visitor:

```
select uniqid, max(whenseenlast) from history group by uniqid
```

and

```
select uniqid, min(whenseenlast) from history group by uniqid
```

then select the records that match them for your history table, something like this:

```
select frst.uniqid, whenseenfirst, whereseenfirst, whenseenlast, whereseenlast
from
(select h.uniqid, mn.mnseen as whenseenfirst, h.whereseenlast as whereseenfirst
    from history h
    join (select uniqid, min(whenseenlast) as mnseen from history group by uniqid) mn
    on mn.mnseen = h.whenseenlast and mn.uniqid = h.uniqid) frst,
(select h.uniqid, mx.mxseen as whenseenlast, h.whereseenlast as whereseenlast
    from history h
    join (select uniqid, max(whenseenlast) as mxseen from history group by uniqid) mx
    on mx.mxseen = h.whenseenlast and mx.uniqid = h.uniqid) lst
where frst.uniqid = lst.uniqid
```

You can verify it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ea2cd/12)

Comment: Thanks!!! I think this will be the solution I ll be back for marking as a solution when I am done on the server.

Comment: "Is this your home assignment for database class?"  -  something like that :)

Comment: There will be problems with this solution if there are 2 (or more) records with same `max(whenseenlast)` or `min(whenseenlast)`

Comment: Finaly it turned out it DID give more results for one uniqid, but also turned out I am better in linux shell scripting than SQL stuff, so using this solution I could solve my problem exporting the result to csv, running uniq on it and after that importing in the result csv... I know it is an ugly way but at least it solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (uniqid) *
FROM history
ORDER BY uniqid, whenseenlast DESC
```

It will give you last history record for every user (every `DISTINCT uniqid`).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (uniqid) *
FROM history
ORDER BY uniqid, whenseenlast
```

To get the first history record.

```
INSERT INTO visitors (uniqid, whereseenlast, whenseenlast, whenseenfirst, whenseenlast ...)
SELECT seen_last.uniqid, seen_last.whereseenlast, seen_last.whenseenlast, seen_first.whereseenlast, seen_first.whenseenlast ...
FROM 
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (uniqid) *
      FROM history
      ORDER BY uniqid, whenseenlast DESC) seen_last
JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (uniqid) *
      FROM history
      ORDER BY uniqid, whenseenlast) seen_first
  ON seen_last.uniqid = seen_first.uniqid
```

It will rebuild your table.

Details: [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

Comment: I dont understand this seen_last.uniqid seen_last.whereseenlast seen_last.whenseenlast things. Could You please explain?

Comment: @ykat `seen_last` is the alias for first sub `SELECT`. `seen_last.uniqid` means field `uniqid` from `SELECT` with alias `seen_last`.

Answer (score 0):

select
    h1.uniqid,
    h1.whereseenlast as whereseenfirst,
    h1.whenseenlast as whenseefirst,
    h3.whereseenlast,
    h3.whenseenlast
from history h1
left join history h2
    on h1.uniqid = h2.uniqid
    and h1.whenseenlast < h2.whenseenlast

join history h3
    on h1.uniqid = h3.uniqid
left join history h4
    on h3.uniqid = h4.uniqid
    and h3.whenseenlast > h4.whenseenlast

where
    h2.uniqid is null
    and h4.uniqid is null

Comment: :( ERROR: column h1.when does not exist
LINE 10: h1.when < h2.when

Comment: Fixed field names for you. Tested on Igor's sandbox.